# incompatible pointer type assigning in function pointer usage

Tags: c, casting

I'm trying to use function pointer in my code, the code is as below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef void (*PFUNC)(int);

typedef struct tag_FUNC_INFO_S
{
    PFUNC callback;
    int   index;
} FUNC_INFO_S;

PFUNC callback_print(int index)
{
    printf("[callback] index = %d\n", index);
    return NULL;
}

void thread_test(FUNC_INFO_S *info)
{
    info->callback(info->index);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid;

    FUNC_INFO_S info;
    info.callback = callback_print;
    info.index    = 777;

    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, (void *)thread_test, &info);

    printf("main printing\n");

    return 0;
}
```

After compiled the code with "gcc -Wall xxx.c -o xxx -lpthread", the compiler complains with the following message:

func_ptr_test.c:30:16: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'PFUNC' (aka 'void (*)(int)') from 'PFUNC (int)' (aka 'void (*(int))(int)' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types] info.callback = callback_print;

But, if I change the code from

```
info.callback = callback_print;
```

to

```
info.callback = (PFUNC)callback_print;
```

No warning message comes out any more. But, even without type casting, I think the "info.callback" has totally the same type with "callback_print", so I'm wondering why the warning message comes out. Does anyone have idea about this?

Comment: I do believe: `PFUNC callback_print(int index)` --> `void callback_print(int index)`

Comment: the functions being used as threads MUST have the syntax: `void * functionName( void *)`  Your thread functions do not have that syntax

Comment: near the end of the `main()` function the statement(s): `int *status = NULL;  pthread_join( tid, &status );` is missing

Comment: the first few lines of `thread_test()` should be: `void *thread_test( void *param)  {  FUNC_INFO_S info = *( FUNC_INFO*)param;`

Comment: strongly suggest replacing: `gcc -Wall xxx.c -o xxx -lpthread` with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 xxx.c -o xxx -lpthread`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes, exploring what is beneath the surface helps to understand the picture better.

In C, you can pretty much treat the function name as a pointer to that function. Take a look at the example below

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    (*printf)("test\n");
    return 0;
}
```

In the code snippet above, we could simply use `printf()` instead of `(*printf)()`, and it actually is the usual way you would call a function.

Another example is the [signal() library function](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=signal&sektion=3&manpath=freebsd-release-ports) (yes, I am a FreeBSD user), whose definition is given as

```
 void
 (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);
```

When you call `signal()`, the convention is

```
void
handle(int sig)
{
    ...
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    (void) signal(SIGUSR1, handle);
    ...
}
```

Now, can you see the trick here? Although, `signal()` is declared to take `void (*func)(int)` (i.e. a pointer to a function returning void and taking a single int argument), we pass the *name of a function* of that type as the second argument to `signal()`.

Going back to your question, `PFUNC` is an alias for a pointer to a function returning void and taking a single int argument. By declaring `callback` as `PFUNC callback` you are saying your compiler that, the `callback` variable will point a function which returns void and takes a single int argument.

So, you should have

```
void callback_print(int index) /* now you have a void ()(int) */
{
    printf("[callback] index = %d\n", index);
}
```

to match what is expected as the lvalue of your assignment performed by `info.callback = callback_print;`.

Answer (score 4):

You can't define a function with a function pointer typedef.  You just need to define the function to match the typedef:

```
void callback_print(int index)
{
    printf("[callback] index = %d\n", index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have have a wrong understanding of the funcion pointer.

You can change your

```
PFUNC callback_print(int index)
```

prototype as

```
void callback_print(int index)
```

And all things should be fine. Why the compiler is not happy is because

```
PFUNC callback_print(int index)
```

prototype is `void (* (*)(int))(int)` but PFUNC type is `void(*)(int)`
So your return type is `void(*)(int)` not `void`